# Mongodb dynamic schema to save any data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We often define a schema like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Account = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('account', Account);
```

And we have to pass in object that matches the schema otherwise nothing worked. But says I want to save something that's dynamic, and I don't even know what are them for example it can be

```
{'name':'something',birthday:'1980-3-01'}
```

or just anything else

```
{'car':'ferrari','color':'red','qty':1}
```

How do you set the schema then?

Comment: excellent question

Comment: did u find a solution for this so far? It is indeed a very interesting question

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose has a [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-mixed-js) [schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) that allows a field to be any object.

```
var Account = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    anyobject: Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

Comment: this is just allowed to add 3rd property with any kind of data, I mean the property is dynamic, not just the value. The value I can do string.

Comment: The properties in the Mixed object open  `{ username: "u", password: "p", metadata: { myfield: 1 } }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strict: false` option to your existing schema definition by supplying it as a second parameter in `Schema` constructor:

**Example**

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    Name : {type: String},
    Password : {type: String}
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

You can also use `Mixed` type

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
   Name : {type: String},
   Email : {type: String},
    Tasks : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
}, {strict: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

Comment: If strict is set to false why do you need to define Name and Email?